# Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, hadoop

I have read a lot on the internet, but found no solution for my problem.
I use Hadoop 2.6.0.

The main goal for the *MapReduce* is to run through a *SequenceFile* and do some analysis on the key/value pairs.

```
2015-01-29 10:09:50,554 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
2015-01-29 10:09:50,554 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
2015-01-29 10:09:50,554 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 23342; bufvoid = 104857600
2015-01-29 10:09:50,554 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26213840(104855360); length = 557/6553600
2015-01-29 10:09:50,570 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
2015-01-29 10:09:50,577 FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:2359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:2491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Here the output from STDOUT

```
15/01/29 10:09:35 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
15/01/29 10:09:35 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.gz]

15/01/29 10:09:36 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8040
15/01/29 10:09:37 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15/01/29 10:09:37 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15/01/29 10:09:37 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1422374835659_0059
15/01/29 10:09:37 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1422374835659_0059
15/01/29 10:09:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:8088/proxy/application_1422374835659_0059/
15/01/29 10:09:37 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1422374835659_0059
15/01/29 10:09:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1422374835659_0059 running in uber mode : false
15/01/29 10:09:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/01/29 10:09:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422374835659_0059_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/01/29 10:09:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422374835659_0059_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/01/29 10:10:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1422374835659_0059_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
15/01/29 10:10:10 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/01/29 10:10:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1422374835659_0059 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1422374835659_0059_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

15/01/29 10:10:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=4
        Launched map tasks=4
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=1
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=37910
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=18955
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=18955
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=38819840
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
```

My configurations are nearly default, nothing related to the Java heap size.

I've also tried this, which does not made a difference.

```
<property>
        <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
        <value>-Xmx1024m</value>
</property>
```

The main programm on the master starts with **`-Xmx512m`**, while the container on the node started with **`-Xmx1024m`** as expected.

Also editing the `hadoop-env.sh` to the following, does not help:

```
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx2048m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

Configurations in my MapReduce application:

```
conf.setInt("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", 2048);
conf.setInt("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb", 1024);
```

**EDIT 1 29.01:**

With `-Xmx2048m` I received the same error.

With `-Xmx3072m` I go to the following error:

```
Error: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.DataOutputBuffer.write(DataOutputBuffer.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:2359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:2491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

With `-Xmx4096m` I go to a totally different error and I don't understand why he now wants to use 5GB of virtual memory:

```
Container [pid=61687,containerID=container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 866.8 MB of 2 GB physical memory used; 5.0 GB of 4.2 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 61687 61685 61687 61687 (bash) 0 0 12640256 304 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx4096m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/hduser/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1422374835659_0064/container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/userlogs/application_1422374835659_0064/container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.97.83.13 33802 attempt_1422374835659_0064_m_000000_0 2 1>/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/userlogs/application_1422374835659_0064/container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002/stdout 2>/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/userlogs/application_1422374835659_0064/container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002/stderr  
    |- 61692 61687 61687 61687 (java) 629 149 5384613888 221601 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx4096m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/hduser/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1422374835659_0064/container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/userlogs/application_1422374835659_0064/container_1422374835659_0064_01_000002 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.97.83.13 33802 attempt_1422374835659_0064_m_000000_0 2 

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

**EDIT 2 29.01**

Even with everthing commented out in the map() function the error appears.

With only 10 key/value pairs in the *SequenceFile* (132.93 KB) everthing works fine.

**EDIT 3 30.01**

Here the minimalized Source, which produces the same error.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class Dummy implements Tool {

    private Configuration conf;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        int res = ToolRunner.run(conf, new Dummy(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public void setConf(Configuration conf) {
        // Set some Job options
        conf.set("dfs.blocksize", "16m");

        // set heap size
        // conf.set("yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts", "-Xmx1024m");
        // conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts", "-Xmx200m");

        // request more memory be the ressourcemanager
        conf.setInt("mapreduce.map.memory.mb", 2048);
        conf.setInt("mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb", 1024);

        // IO space
        // conf.setInt("mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb", 256);

        // Since we have lots of small tasks we should reduce overhead
        // conf.setInt("mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks", -1);

        this.conf = conf;
    }

    /**
     * configuration getter
     */
    @Override
    public Configuration getConf() {
        return conf;
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

        // Configure the job
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Dummy");

        job.setJarByClass(Dummy.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

        // Set number of Reducers to number of actions + 1 for error log
        // job.setNumReduceTasks(action_count+2);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class); // Global Aggregation

        // Set output
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        // Enable record skipping for failed Maps
        // SkipBadRecords.setMapperMaxSkipRecords(conf, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        // only create a output file it there is content
        // LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);

        // set input and output for job
        // FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, repo.getRepository());
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path("/test/test.seq"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/test/out"));

        // Execute Job
        int res = 0;
        // job.submit();
        res = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

        return res;

    }

    public static class Map extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        @Override
        protected void map(Text key, Text value, Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> value, Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would monitor the process using jvisualvm to confirm the heap is the size you think it should be and if you still get an error give it more memory.  The maximum memory should be the size you would rather die than use more.

Comment: Seems to me like you're telling Hadoop it should feel free to use 2048 MB for its Map operation, but then you're telling the JVM it should use no more than 1024 MB total. Your penultimate code block ups this to 2048 MB, but you're still not allowing any room for non-Hadoop stuff. Can you up `-Xmx` to 3072 MB, at least?

Comment: I've tried -Xmx2048m, -Xmx3072m and -Xmx4096m. See the main post.

Comment: I profiled the mapreduce process with visualvm and saw that the heap size was max 380MB and only 150MB used.

Comment: For us to see why your job is running out of memory we would probably need to see your code. Perhaps you are creating memory-intensive objects every map() that could instead be created once in setup() and re-used every map()?

Comment: See the main post under EDIT 3.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got into the same problem.
I am using Oracle VM for studying hadoop. The base memory allocated was 512 MB and I was getting the same error:

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Then I increased it to 1024MB and then I am able to run the MR programs successfully.

Comment: This probably should be a comment, yet it could answer the question. I edited it and I'll let others decide :p